# Struggling with bsearch implementation in C

Tags: c, bsearch

I have an array

```
char* m[] = {"AA", "AC", "AG", "AT", "CA", "CC", "CG", "CT", "GA", "GC", "GG", "GT", "TA", "TC", "TG", "TT"};
```

and Im trying to get the index of the entry that matches  `pseq = (char*)malloc(2);`

I am just using a basic compare function right now, as I hope to create a specific one later

```
int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
        return strcmp(a, b);
}

size_t mlen = sizeof(m)/sizeof(m[0]);
```

My attempt at bsearch is:

`char* q  = bsearch(&pseq, m, mlen, sizeof(m[0]), compare);`

However, every return is NULL.
But `compare(pseq, m[5]) = 0` for pseq = "CC"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pointers passed to `compare` are pointers to `char*`, so you have to dereference them to get `char*` that point at strings to be compared.

```
int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
        return strcmp(*(char**)a, *(char**)b);
}
```

Also

```
pseq = (char*)malloc(2);
```

looks bad because

- 2-element array is too small for storing string like "CC" because there are no room to store the terminating null-character.
- Casting results of `malloc()` in C is [discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: As a follow on, I am trying to use ` int pos=((int)q-(int)m[0])/sizeof(m[0]); ` to get the index  of the match, but its giving me crazy big numbers. for example: 

q is at position 1367400520

m is at position 46039045

pos 165170184

Comment: Subtracting the first element `m[0]` is a bad idea. You should subtract `(int)m` instead of `(int)m[0]`. Changing the type of `q` to `char**` and subtracting the pointers directly `int pos = q - m;` is better.

Comment: Thank you so much for you help! You have made my friday end on a good note !!